# SharePoint Online: site url rename error

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, error, site, rename

I have a sub-site in SharePoint Online with a document library containing large numbers of items. I want to rename the URL of the site. I tried multiple ways including site settings & PowerShell but getting error

> The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold enforced by the administrator.

I tried `$Web.ServerRelativeUrl = $NewURL` in PowerShell but get same error. Also I cannot migrate the document library to new location or delete items.

Can someone suggest any working solution?

Answer (score -1):

This error is not about PowerShell script but dealing with large document library.

Since we cannot change the limit in SharePoint Online, we can only add indexes to columns in the large document library via `Library Settings > Indexed Columns` and see if it can overcome the list view threshold.

But still, the best practice would be to maintain the large numbers of files in multiple libraries. Having a large document library which contains exceeds the list view thresh will lead to future issues.

Reference:

[Manage large lists and libraries in SharePoint.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-large-lists-and-libraries-in-sharepoint-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59)

Comment: This answer is not related to the question at all, but carries the same bad practice MS has in their own technical community forum where moderators just answer something to be able to suggest and mark the post answered although OP question is not answered. The reason why people have moved away from Microsoft community forums to StackExchange is to get rid of these nonsense answers.